# TypeError on method on function/classes attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having problems to make some verifications and alterations with the return of a `get()` method:

```py
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, turnNum=1):
        self._turnNum = turnNum
    
    def set_turnNum(self, turnNum):
        self._turnNum = turnNum

    def get_turnNum(self):
        return self._turnNum
```

But I'm getting errors every time I try something like:

```
num = Foo()
num.set_turnNum(13)
if num.get_turnNum % 2 == 0:
    print('Not works after all...')
    ...
```

I got this error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'method' and 'int'
```

If I try to convert to `int`:

```
num = Foo()
num.set_turnNum(13)
if int(num.get_turnNum) % 2 == 0:
    print('Not works after all...')
...
```

Then I got this other error message:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'method'
```

As can be seen, I'm trying with a protected attribute. But, for the sake of DIY, I'd also tried with public and private attributes too. Unfortunately, with Python 3.5.2 and 3.6.1, I'm getting the same results.

What would be the correct way to do that in Python?

Comment: It's not an attribute, it's a method: `get_turnNum() `. You probably want to look into [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_turnNum` is a method, so if you do `num.get_turnNum` it will return a bound method. You need to call it `num.get_turnNum()` - notice the ()

Alternatively, you can use a [`@property`](http://stackabuse.com/python-properties/) decorator.

```
@property
def turnNum(self):
    return self._turnNum

@turnNum.setter
def turnNum(self, value):
    self._turnNum = value


num = Foo()
num.turnNum = 13
if num.turnNum % 2 == 0:
    print('Working...')
```